# Multiply by logical while ignoring blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a summing criteria that is based on the length of the reference cell. For example if the data is:

```
     A | B 
1| 1.1 | 1   |
2| 1.2 | 0.5 |
3| 1.21| 3   |
```

I want to sum the column B values if the corresponding cell in column A (a text column) has a single decimal (i.e. length 3). For example: LEN(A1)=3 is true, LEN(A2)=3 is true, but LEN(A3)=3 is false, so the sum should be 1.5.

Since it seems it's not possible to do something like the following

```
=SUMIF(A1:A3,"LEN(A1:A3)=3",B1:B3)
```

I set out to do this with an array formula:

```
{=SUM(B1:B3*(LEN(A1:A3)=3))
```

This works fine for this simple test case, but the real data has blanks (or more specifically, cells that are set to "" by another formula). The internet suggests using PRODUCT() to multiply while ignoring blanks, but PRODUCT() also ignores logicals. I tried casting my logicals to integers, which works fine:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B3,INT(LEN(A1:A3)=3))}
```

However, in my real case, the condition (argument to INT) is an AND statement. When looking at evaluation of this formula with the formula debugger, it looks like the AND statement receives two arguments, both of which are logical arrays, but collapses them to a single logical rather than an array of logicals.

...so now I'm stuck. Is there any way to write a formula for a conditional sum where
-The condition refers back to the reference cell (so I can't use SUMIF)
-The condition is complex (requires AND, so array formulas are out)
-The data contains blanks (requires PRODUCT instead of *)

Comment: Your `SUMPRODUCT` formula works fine for your example, and it doesn't need to be an array formula.  You mention your "real case," which requires an AND statement.  Can you include it as an example?

Comment: The traditional way to represent AND with arrays is to multiply the condition arrays since, as you point out, AND collapses the arrays into single values (which makes sense in many contexts).

Comment: Use extra columns - that is what makes a spreadsheet so powerful. It will simplify the formulas you are trying to make, and cut down on errors. Hide them when done.

Comment: @maybeWeCouldStealAVan - Great point. I was able to make the formula work this way. I ended up splitting things out to make them simpler, but your comment did answer the specific question asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one helper column needed in which you calculate the length of the contents of the cells in column A. Then you can simply use SUMIF. This is a fast and general solution.

If a helper column is really not an option, then you could use an array formula that combines SUM and IF.

```
{=SUM(IF((LEN($A$1:$A$10000)=3),$B$1:$B$10000))}
```

[image]

Cell B5 contains ="".

SUM and SUMIF can both deal with not numeric contents. They simply ignore it.

Comment: The helper columns were slightly more complicated in the real case, but it was still the right way to go. It reduced the summing formula to a simple SUMIF. Should have thought of this in the first place...